# How do you find minefields on the map?

Tags: mad-max

I cannot seem to locate minefields from the Vantage Outpost balloons. Do I just need to drive around with the dog and hope I come across them, or is there a way to pinpoint them on the map, like with scarecrows or snipers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Just drive around with the dog.**

The mines spawn only when you are nearby. You can get yourself killed when you step on it. You won't actually see a mine until you bring the dog to sniff it out.

I had tried looking through the sniper scope from long distances, walking there, driving around on the ground without a dog, etc. and yet I could not see a mine even once.

Comment: This is based purely on personal experience completing the game, I have no other references to add.

Comment: An unfortunate "feature" for the game, but your experience is more than mine, so I'll trust it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can find them in the magnum opus, but you have to drive into them for them to be marked on the map. Black fingers will make a comment when you get close.

Comment: While yhe dog is more reliable, you are correct, you can get notified of the firlds in the magnum opus. You just need to practically be on top of them.